# Print json from api in React

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, json

I have a php api that selects the database and returns this data in json, I would like to show them in a table in React App. I tried this way but got no result:

```
import React from 'react'
import JsonData from 'http://localhost/index.php' //My test api is index.php
 function Body(){
    const DisplayData=JsonData.map(
        (info)=>{
            return(
                <tr>
                    <td>{info.id}</td>
                    <td>{info.name}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        }
    )
 
    return(
        <div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 
                    
                    {DisplayData}
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
             
        </div>
    )
 }
 
 export default Body;
```

Comment: You may want to swap the node.js tag for PHP, and maybe remove the react-native tag if it's not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code,

first you should use an http client to fetch your data e.g. `fetch`, `axios`, etc

second you should use a `state` to manage your data because you should re-render your component after your data is fetched, or you may reconsider your components composition in a way that your component get mounted in the page only after your data is ready (and the pass the ready data as prop).

this is a working example using your code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-chaum-uxwexq?file=/src/App.js

Here is the request function

```
async function fetchData() {
  const url = "https://dummyjson.com/carts";
  const r = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  return r.carts[0].products;
}
```

This defined the state and makes a call after the component is mounted:

```
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);
  async function fetchRows() {
    setRows(await fetchData());
  }
  React.useEffect(() => fetchRows, []);
```

also consider using a `key` attribute when you're rendering a list using `.map()`

Answer (score 2):

You can't make an API call that way in react.

To make the API call you can use the `fetch` function, or rely on external libraries such as [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

**example with fetch:**

```js
componentDidMount() {
    // Simple GET request using fetch
    fetch('http://localhost/index.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ myCoolJSON: data}));
}
```

Remember that the call is made asynchronously.

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out that the OP is using a function not a class so `componentDidMount` doesn't make much sense in that context.